# Uncaught TypeError: r is not a function

Tags: jquery

I've definitely linked to the jQuery UI javascript and CSS files correctly - when I view the page source, they're all there. Why am I still getting this error?

```
<script src="Js/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
<script src="Js/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>

<script src="Js/effects.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JQuery/custom.js"></script>
<link href="Css/nivo-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Don't see `jQuery` loaded

Comment: i have already loaded dat on top

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Check for conflicts.

Comment: how to check it!! im new to it

Comment: looks like you've included the nivo slider js files twice - I think the .pack is just the minified version of the one above it

Answer (score -1):

You have to load dependencies first. It looks like the first script you are loading is a jQuery plugin, which depends on jQuery to work.  So therefore, jQuery should be loaded ***before*** that plugin.  Order matters.

Comment: i loaded jquery on top ..but prblm still persits

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem would be solved if you use a newer version of Jquery

Comment: This should probably be a comment instead of an answer.